# Как объявить ссылочную переменную в Angular

Tags: angular

Я создал компонент edit-book.component.ts, в котором описана ссылочная переменная:

```
book: BookModel | undefined;
```

инициализируется она в этом методе:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.book= this.data[0];
  ...
```

Вот файл описание объекта book:

```
export class BookModel {
  id: string;
  bookName: string;

  constructor(id: string, bookName: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.bookName= bookName;
  }
}
```

Когда я прописываю в файле edit-book.component.html

```
[(ngModel)]="book.bookName"
```

то компилятор ругается:

```
error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Как правильно указать тип переменной book?
Если пишу так, то компилятор требует выполнить инициализацию или указать undefined:

```
book: BookModel;
```

Comment: [(ngModel)]="book?.bookName" - так скушает?

Comment: Нет:  error NG5002: Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 24 in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `ngOnInit` отрабатывает после инициализации компонента, а значит и

```
[(ngModel)]="book.bookName"
```

На этапе инициализации будет

```
[(ngModel)]="undefined.bookName"
```

Данную проблему можно обойти временной инициализацией переменной

```
book: BookModel = new BookModel();
```

В таком случае, как только ваша `data` придёт, ссылка на объект поменяется в вашем `onInit` методе